# How to detach vmdk using vboxmanage cli

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have my sandbox created using vboxmanage cli tool which created vmdk file.

I converted it from .vmdk to .vdi, as i wanted to compress it. then i attached this newly created .vdi file.

Now i want to detach the vmdk file as i don't want it any more.
Can you please suggest me what should be the command for the same?

List of my HDDs are:

```
$ vboxmanage list hdds
UUID:           f3b90783-abe7-4549-91aa-39aa6161f103
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/ankit/VirtualBox VMs/asr-vm/asr-sandbox-3.5.0-lb1404x64-disk1.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       65536 MBytes

UUID:           1b9a4eff-f1bd-4c4e-ae48-8f11b8003244
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/ankit/VirtualBox VMs/asr-vm/asr-sandbox-3.5.0-lb1404x64-disk1.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Capacity:       65536 MBytes
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the solution for this is to attach that `medium` with `emptydrive` or `none`. that means for that particular `port` and `device` you are attaching an `emptydrive` or `none`.

```
vboxmanage storageattach "asr-vm" --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --medium none
```

or

```
vboxmanage storageattach "asr-vm" --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --medium emptydrive
```

As per docs `medium none` is a better option.

Comment: +1, however `vboxmanage storageattach [vm-name] --storagectl SATA --port 1 --medium none` is a better option

Comment: When i try it with emptydrive or none i get an error: VBoxManage: error: Could not find a controller named 'SATA'

Comment: Not very sure but I think it should match the storagectl type of your VM. try this, check the value of "Storage Controller Name" with vboxmanage showvminfo VM_NAME and try replacing SATA with that name.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering why `none` is a better option than `emptydrive` for the `--medium` flag, the VboxManage docs have this to say:

> `--medium`
>
> Specifies what is to be attached. The following values are supported:
>
> - none: Any existing device should be removed from the given slot.
> - emptydrive: For a virtual DVD or floppy drive only, this makes the device slot behave like a removeable drive into which no media has been inserted.

So given we want to detach (or "remove" it), `none` seems like the correct option.

Source:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storageattach

*This is a reponse to [Mehrdad Hedayati comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463588/how-to-detach-vmdk-using-vboxmanage-cli#comment73984621_41480531) to the accepted answer.*